# How to make a filter from bots? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I can't make a filter.

The bot shows 6 members of the server , with the bot.

How can I make the bot not be included in this number

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("74721732.........");
setInterval(function () {
   var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
   var memberCountChannel = client.channels.cache.get("81358139.........");
  memberCountChannel.setName(`Members: ${memberCount}`);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Per the [discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object), a member is a bot when its value `member.user.bot` is true. So your filter should be correct. Can you add a `console.log({guild.members})` line inside your `setInterval()` and provide the output?

Comment: [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter's callback function is correct, it removes every bot from the collection.

The problem is that `guild.members` returns a [manager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager), not a collection. It means it won't have a `filter()` method. You should use `guild.members.cache` as it returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of guild members and collections do have a `.filter()` method:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('74721732.........');
setInterval(function () {
  const memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.user.bot).size;
  const memberCountChannel = client.channels.cache.get('81358139.........');
  memberCountChannel.setName(`Members: ${memberCount}`);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It turned out, but outputs the number 0.
Although it should be 5

Comment: I've just checked it on my bot and it works as expected. Are you sure there is no typo in your filter's callback function?

Comment: I double-checked, it's all right.
But writes 0

Comment: Could you check the number before the filter? `console.log(guild.members.cache.size);`

Comment: `console.log(guild.members.cache.size);` — 1

Comment: So the filter works, the problem is a bit different now, as `guild.members` only contains a bot. :O